# Процессоры и шина

Tags: многопоточность, архитектура

В многопроцессорной системе один из процессоров хочет произвести чтение, если при арбитраже шина досталась не ему, что происходит с процессором? Если в следующий раз он опять не смог захватить шину, он простаивает пока она не будет ему предоставлена? И всё это время он будет стоять на одной команде?

Comment: В зависимости от планировщика и в зависимости от конкретного алгоритма распределения времени, а так же конкретной архитектуры системы. Он может ожидать пока шина освободиться, может переключится на другой процесс или получить доступ шине. Все слишком в общих чертах в вопросе.

Comment: Подключаю в шине Wishbone процессор на основе PicoBlaze, остановлюсь на том, что если не удалось заполучить шину, отключаю тактовую частоту от процессора, пока пока арбитр не предоставит доступ.

Comment: В данном случаем, по-моему, ничего лучше не придумать, это специфическая особенность многопроцессорной системы.